# How to remove empty space in React and Bootstrap 5

Tags: css, reactjs, bootstrap-5, react-bootstrap

I'm writing a pet project that needs to be mobile responsive and I have a problem with white space in the Carousel component, I don't know how to remove it, can someone help me?

This is looks like page on PC
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ql0FO.jpg

This is looks like mobile devices https://i.stack.imgur.com/FXR25.jpg

And I want to remove the empty space at the bottom, make the carousel responsive, how can I do that?

Here is my component code

```js
import ...

export default class CarouselBox extends Component{
    render(){
        return(
            
                <Carousel>
                    <Carousel.Item>
                        <img className="d-block w-100"
                        src={edinburghView1}
                        alt="Edinburgh_Uni"
                        />
                    <Carousel.Caption>
                        <Nav.Link href='/EdinburghCity'>
                        <h3>Edinburgh city</h3>
                        <p>Edinburgh city view in 2023</p>
                        </Nav.Link>
                    </Carousel.Caption>        
                    </Carousel.Item>
                                
            
        )
    }
}
```

Here is my Footer component

```
import { MDBFooter } from 'mdb-react-ui-kit';

export default class Footer extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <>
    <MDBFooter sticky="bot" bgColor='light' className='text-center text-lg-left' class="fixed-bottom">
      <div className='text-center p-3' style={{
         backgroundColor: '#f8f9fa', 
         marginTop: '0.5%' }}>
        &copy; {new Date().getFullYear()} Copyright:{' '}
        <a className='text-dark' href='https://t.me/koreechdhs'>
          Boiar Kostiatyn
        </a>
      </div>
    </MDBFooter>
            </>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: that's a lot of things you have asked in a single place. Have you tried anything so far to make it responsive?

Comment: I tried to find information on the Internet on how to do this correctly, but I didn’t find the option I needed, I thought they could help me here (at least throw a link to the source)

Comment: Based on the `Carousel` component I'm assuming you're also using React Bootstrap?

Comment: Sure! I'm using it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm somewhat confused what you mean by:

> I want to remove the empty space at the bottom, make the carousel responsive, how can I do that?

I'm assuming the red area here you're talking about?

[image]

That is because, you have

```
sticky="bot"
```

in:

```
<MDBFooter sticky="bot" bgColor='light' className='text-center text-lg-left' class="fixed-bottom">
```

which is doing exactly what you want.

If you want the carousel to be full height you will need to add that in the component at that viewport size, reference [sizing](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/sizing/)

Comment: I tried without fixing the footer on the page, but that makes it even worse :D
Empty space doesn't go anywhere, it just ends up underneath, btw thank you for answer! I will try do it